# c# Deleting a file in System32 folder

Tags: c#

im trying to delete a specific file in system32 but as thats where all the important files is, its very hard to delete things from there. The only way i can do it so far is if i go into the propertys and change the permissions so i have full control over that file and then delete it.

I am trying to do this programmaticly, ive tried numerous ways of changing the permissions on a file but i just get the error "unauthorised", even in elevated cmd using commands like takeown/ it doesnt work, i know if i can do it in cmd, i can do it programmaticly so that would work too.

any help is appriciated

Comment: How about start your program using "Run as Administrator ?"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please specifically describe what you have done so far and provide your code so we can help you.

Comment: You're going to need your program to run as Administrator if you want to force the application to do that:

<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

You can also right click the exe and run as administrator. or run the exe from an elevated command prompt.

If you want to just run it in visual studio you can open visual studios as an administrator.

Comment: Would ask why you want to do that but never mind...

Comment: i have tried running my program as administrator and it didnt work

Comment: ive tried every code snippet that claims to give me full control of a file

Comment: When you try to *write* or *save* to the Windows folder, it redirects you to `\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows`.  The same may be true for System32 and deletes.

Comment: do you know how i would get around that?

Answer (score 4):

You should elevate the permissions due to UAC. Below is a sample which checks if the current user running the app has elevated rights, if not, exits and re-runs the app with Admin rights.

```
WindowsPrincipal pricipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
bool hasAdministrativeRight = pricipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

if (!hasAdministrativeRight)
{
    RunElevated(Application.ExecutablePath);
    this.Close();
    Application.Exit();
}

private static bool RunElevated(string fileName)
{
    //MessageBox.Show("Run: " + fileName);
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    processInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processInfo.FileName = fileName;
    try
    {
        Process.Start(processInfo);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Win32Exception)
    {
        //Do nothing as user cancelled UAC window.
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Take ownership of the file and delete**

```
new Process() { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/k takeown /f C:\Windows\System32\testfile.txt && icacls C:\Windows\System32\testfile.txt /grant %username%:F") }.Start();
File.Delete(@"C:\Windows\System32\testfile.txt");
```

Comment: gives me the same error as when i right click run as administrator, im still not authorised to change the permissions on a file in sys32

Comment: Does UAC popup appear for Admin access ?

Comment: yep, its definitly running as admin, im pretty sure its just because the file is in system32 so it has some extra protection or something

Comment: I've updated my answer adding UseShellExecute = true; Can you check?

Comment: Hmmmm... Interesting. I'll get back you shortly

Comment: even with the shell execute i sitll get the error that im unauthorised

Comment: Are you trying to delete a DLL or some other type of file?

Comment: originally it was an exe, but that worked when i did it manually and wont go back to read only so now im trying with a .xml file

Comment: I managed to delete it. Please check bottom of my answer. What i do is, I take ownership of the file first and then perform a delete. Sorry for the hard coding but i'm sure you'll make it work.

Comment: hmm i tried that and im still getting "Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\locationnotificationsview.XML' is denied." i think its because u tried it with a .txt you made and put in there whereas im trying to delete an actual sys32 file if you get what i mean

Comment: I will try to delete one of my system32 files and let you know :)

Comment: No problems A-Jay. Check my latest answer. I think I made it this time

Answer (score 0):

Further research showed that there is a much better way of doing this. Carry on;

**Create Application Manifest**

By doing this, you don't need to check for admin rights in the app and restart if required. By default, app will launch with the elevated credentials. Simple Add > New Item > Application Manifest to project and uncomment following line ;

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

**Set File Access Permission in Code and Delete File**

There should be a lincense.txt file in System32 folder. We can delete it with the following;

```
        FileInfo insInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\license.txt");
        FileSecurity insFileSecurity = insInfo.GetAccessControl();
        insFileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + System.Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
        insInfo.SetAccessControl(insFileSecurity);
        File.Delete(@"C:\Windows\System32\license.txt");
```

NOTE : Once you set the application.manifest with requirement of elevated permissions, Visual Studio may want to restart with Administrator rights when you start debugging. Simply allow it to restart, your project will be loaded automatically and you can start debugging.

NOTE FOR CLICK-ONCE APPLICATIONS : When elevated permissions are set in the manifest, clickonce applications deny to compile. To fix this, right click on the application project and go to Security tab. Uncheck "Use Click-once Application Security" option and you are good to go.

Hope this helps

Comment: hmm i tried this and the first ime vs told to me restart with admins right so i did and ran the code with no errors but the file is still there, i can open it etc so i try run it again but now it says the file doesnt exist, mabye i did delete it but then i can still actually open the file etc

Comment: so aparently i can delete .txt documents that way but not any other file type specificily .exe unless i change the permisssions manually